# Indexing words in a text by character index. (C)

Tags: c, indexing

Currently working on a short task where I, given a word, have to print out the position of these words by character index. Trying to this in C. Currently trying to fix an issue where, if the word: 'it' is the input, 'it' and 'fit' would count as two occurences of it. Sort of fixed it for cases such as (it)alics by keeping track of the character in front. Unable to replicate backwards. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
void compareWord(char word[], int size){
    char c;
    int index = -1; //Assuming we want first char index in text to be 0.
    char spaceCheck = ' ';
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        index++;
        if (c == word[0]) {
            char storing = c;
            char otherWord[size];
            otherWord[0] = c;
            for (int i = 1; i < size ; i++) {
                    otherWord[i] = (storing = getchar());
                    index++;
            }
            if (((storing = getchar()) == ' ' ) || (storing == '\n')  && (strcmp(word, otherWord) == 0)) {
                index++;
                int wordIndex = index;
                wordIndex -= size;
                printf("%d \n", wordIndex);
            } else
                index++;
        }
        spaceCheck = c;
    }
}

int main() {
    char word[] = "it";
    compareWord(word, 2);
}
```

The variable 'spaceCheck' was me attempting to check if the character before the word is a space or not. Previously had 
 `(spaceCheck == ' ' )` in the long if statement, didn't work.

Comment: Can you please narrow your question?  Try reading [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: One thing: Your `c` variable in `compareWord()` needs to be an int, not a char: http://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html

Comment: `otherWord[i] = (storing = getchar());` You dont check for EOF, here.This could loop forever.

Answer (score 0):

You state the problem is not finding embedded word matches,

Suggest using the function: `strstr()` to search for embedded words

`strstr()` is exposed via the header file: `string.h`

The full syntax:

```
char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

description:  "The  strstr() function finds the first occurrence of the substring needle in the string haystack.  The terminating null bytes ('\0') are  not
       compared."

returned value: "These functions return a pointer to the beginning of the  located  sub‐
       string, or NULL if the substring is not found."